# Decompression time in devtools network - Chrome/Firefox (Gzip / Brotli)

Tags: compression, google-chrome-devtools, gzip, brotli

I want to use brotli to compress some javascript files.
I managed to compress them on the server side using the maximum compression level.
Indeed this compressed file weight less than the GZIP one.
I have for example my file.js.br on the server which will be send to the client if he supports BR encoding.

Ok that's the great, the file weight less, the client downloads it faster.
But what about the decompression time ?
As I compressed with the maximum level I suppose that it takes more time to decompress.

The thing is, maybe in total GZIP + decompression is faster than BROTLI + decompression but I don't know it and I failed my optimization.
**Is that possible to see in the console not only the time to download the file but also the time to decompress it ?**

Thank you in advance.